# How to copy and manipulate a two dimensional array

Tags: java

I'm trying to copy a two dimensional array, then manipulate the data inside the copied version and compare it to the original one.

```
int[][] magicSquare2 = magicSquare;
```

I tried this but i realised it refers to the same object.

Comment: Read more about how Java handles references/copies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 2):

To create a copy of an array in Java you use [System.arraycopy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)). So if for exmaple you have an array (doesn't matter one or multidimentional) then,

```
int[] array = {4, 2, 5};
int[] copy = new int[3];

System.arraycopy(array, 0, copy, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
int[] array = {23, 43, 55, 12};

int newLength = array.length;

int[] copiedArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, newLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

For two dimensional arrays copy the first dimension. Then repeat the process with the elements in the first dimension.
**NOTE:**If you don't copy the elements or clone them. They will refer to the original elements.

```java
int[][] a2d={{0,1},{1,0}};
Int[][] copy=Arrays.copy(a2d,a2d.length);
for(int i=0;i<a2d.length;i++){
int[] e=copy[i];
//you might prefer doing null check before you proceed.
copy[i]=Arrays.copy(e,e.length);
}
```